# Why is my code returning an error when I put in duplicate values?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

It is an app made using Flask.
The following is the forms.py file

```
import flask_wtf
import wtforms
import wtforms.validators
from yff.models import User


class RegistrationForm(flask_wtf.FlaskForm):
    username = wtforms.StringField('Username',
                            validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired(), wtforms.validators.Length(min=3, max=20)])
    email = wtforms.StringField('Email', 
                        validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired(),
                                            wtforms.validators.Email()])
    password = wtforms.PasswordField('Password', validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired()])
    confirmPassword = wtforms.PasswordField('Confirm Password', 
                        validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired(), wtforms.validators.EqualTo('password')])
    remember = wtforms.BooleanField('Remember me')
    submit = wtforms.SubmitField('Create Account')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            return wtforms.validators.ValidationError(message='This username is already taken. Please choose a different one.')
    
    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            return wtforms.validators.ValidationError(message='This email is already taken. Please choose a different one.')


class LoginForm(flask_wtf.FlaskForm):
    email = wtforms.StringField('Email', 
                        validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired(),
                                            wtforms.validators.Email()])
    password = wtforms.PasswordField('Password', validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired()])
    remember = wtforms.BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = wtforms.SubmitField('Login')
```

The following is the models.py file

```
from yff import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    profile_pic = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, default="default.jpg")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.username}, {self.email}'
```

I get an ugly error screen instead of flashing the messages in the validate_email() and validate_username() functions like I want to. The code should ideally show the specified messages.

Here is my template by the way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="post">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="flash-msg">{{ message }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
                <div id="username-field">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-label") }}
                    {% if form.username.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                            <span>{{ message }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ form.username(class='form-el') }}
                </div>
                <div id="email-field">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                            <span>{{ message }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ form.email(class='form-el') }}
                </div>
                <div id="password-field">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-label") }}
                        {% if form.password.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ message }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {{ form.password(class='form-el') }}
                </div>
                <div id="confirm-pass-field">
                    {{ form.confirmPassword.label(class="form-label") }}
                        {% if form.confirmPassword.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.confirmPassword.errors %}
                                <span>{{ message }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {{ form.confirmPassword(class='form-el') }}
                </div>
                <div id="submit-field">
                    {{ form.submit(class='submit-btn') }}
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="check">
                <small id="al-account">
                    Already have an account? Head to our <a id="check-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login page</a>
                </small>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'user' for key 'user.username'") [SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, password, email, profile_pic) VALUES (%(username)s, %(password)s, %(email)s, %(profile_pic)s)] [parameters: {'username': 'user', 'password': '$2b$12$hqMuP11r7nKeYgU.NGLeauxOwWTJ5.zt0YgOXL4cZUOLdRC0klGie', 'email': 'email@gmail.com', 'profile_pic': 'default.jpg'}] (Background on this error at: sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "ugly error screen"? Post the full error message, preferrably.

Comment: Is that really a **minimal** [mre]? Have you attempted to narrow down the problem *location* - if so your mre should reflect that - even if you need to construct a facsimile of your code to do it.

Comment: I have no idea where the problem lies, @wwii. That is the reason I uploaded the files where I suspect the problem to be.

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments, and they usually appear in order of votes, not chronologically. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: Alright, I did it @Robert

Comment: Add the code for the route that handles when your form is submitted